# How can I delete parent after click event on child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have anchor tag and this is my HTML

```
<tr data-id="5" class="rowshow">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl06" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl08" type="text" value="1000" />
    </td>
    <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="6" class="rowshow">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl14" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="ctl16" type="text" value="1000" />
    </td>
    <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And i want delete after click on "a" tag ajax success without refresh my page .and this my script

And this my script

```
$(".deleteBtn").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest(".rowshow").data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EditFood.aspx/delete",
        data: "{'id':" + id + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            $(this).parent(".rowshow").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what you want to delete?

Comment: i want to delet my tr from table and from my dom

Comment: you can try like this `$(this).parents('tr:first').remove();`. I'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console, like 500 status code?

Comment: @dfsq no i dont have error

Comment: @AkashChavda it's not working i just want delet from my DOM without refreshing

Comment: So you are sure you enter success callback?

Comment: @dfsq it's delete from database because when i refresh my page  It's gone

Comment: you can change in ajax `data: { id : id }` and added alert or console.log in your success function and check alert or console.log is call or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The `$(this)` is not accessible inside ajax as `this` refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call and *NOT* the button clicked. Cache the object before the ajax call and then use it.
2. You need to change `.parent(".rowshow")` to `.closest(".rowshow")`. `parent` only looks at the immediate parent, it doesn't scan up.

So:

```
$(".deleteBtn").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).closest(".rowshow").data("id");
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EditFood.aspx/delete",
        data: "{'id':" + id + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            $this.closest(".rowshow").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Also, Add `event.preventDefault()` to avoid default action of `a`.

**Live example** using `setTimeout` to simulate the `ajax` call:

```js
$(".deleteBtn").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).closest(".rowshow").data("id");
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.closest(".rowshow").remove();
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="5" class="rowshow">
      <td>0</td>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl06" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl08" type="text" value="1000" />
      </td>
      <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="6" class="rowshow">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl14" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="ctl16" type="text" value="1000" />
      </td>
      <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` and it should work. Check the current answer.

Comment: @ShaunakD `prevendDefault` is not necessary in this case, it will make no difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the additional notes and suggestions. I had already added the points at the bottom. But I guess you did the right thing by bulleting the points at top. @ aleireza Thank him.

Comment: @ShaunakD: Ah, you had indeed. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try following working JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('.deleteBtn').click(function(event) {
       var $this = $(this);
       
            $this.parent().remove();

    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr data-id="5" class="rowshow">
        <td>0</td>
        <td><input name="ctl06" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" /></td>
        <td><input name="ctl08" type="text" value="1000" /></td>
        <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="6" class="rowshow">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input name="ctl14" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" /></td>
        <td><input name="ctl16" type="text" value="1000" /></td>
        <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Check [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/efxz3uzy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check following:

```js
$(".deleteBtn").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<table><tr data-id="5" class="rowshow">
        <td>0</td>
        <td><input name="ctl06" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" /></td>
        <td><input name="ctl08" type="text" value="1000" /></td>
        <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="6" class="rowshow">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input name="ctl14" type="text" value="قرمه سبزی" /></td>
        <td><input name="ctl16" type="text" value="1000" /></td>
        <td><a Class="deleteBtn">X</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```